# Selenium not working on windows VPS server

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium

I have done my coding for automation of forms using **selenium** then I purchased windows VPS server to run my application. But now I am unable to run my application using **selenium** on this server.

Can you please suggest me any alternative?

I need to open my website in internet explorer only and make auto fill of forms in that and submit it.

Comment: "run my application using selenium" you don't run your application using Selenium. your server software runs, and then you configure Selenium to *point* at the URL/Port that your server is running on.

Comment: but there is no option of run my application using selenium on server